# When to use value classes and when to use reference class in C++/CLI

Tags: .net, c++-cli

I am writing a very simple GUI in Visual C++. I created a Windows Forms Application in Visual Studio and almost all variables and functions I need will be members of my MainForm class.

But, I have a need for some external data structures that will store values corresponding to the GUI elements. I plan to use instances of these data structures to read values from a file and then update the GUI elements (using a function part of MainForm that takes the data structures as arguments).

My question is whether I should make these data structures value structs or reference structs? They are very simple and only store basic variables (int's, bool's, some enums). I will have an instance of the main data structure in my MainForm as well as a pointer to class that contains static instances of these data structures (so called "presets" that can be used to set the GUI elements without loading a file).

Here is the basic code. Which of the structs here should be ref and which should be value?

```
ref/value struct sub_params_t
{
     int my_sub_int;
     bool my_sub_bool;
     enum_t my_sub_enum;
}

ref/value struct params_t
{
     int my_int;
     bool my_bool;
     enum_t my_enum;
     sub_params_t my_sub_params;
}

ref/value struct presets_t
{
     static params_t my_first_preset;
     static params_t my_second_preset;
     static presets_t() { //use static constructor to initialize static instances }
}     

public ref class MainForm : public System::Windows::Forms::Form
{
      private:
          params_t current_params; //will be updated when file is loaded and used to set GUI elements
          presets_t^ my_presets; //will be used to set GUI elements without loading a file
          System::Void UpdateGUIelements(params_t^ params);

}
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: I would generally use `ref class` everywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple rule you can use is that a value type should not require a default constructor to initialize it, contains no more than 4 members and doesn't require more than 16 bytes of storage in 32-bit mode.

The default constructor requirement is a plain one, a value type cannot have one.  The member/storage requirement ensures that copying the value is not too expensive when it gets passed as an argument to a method and that there will be decent odds that the value can be stored in CPU registers instead of memory.

You have to be careful in your code, arbitrarily applying the ^ hat to a variable of a value type is always a mistake, one that the compiler doesn't warn you about.  The value will be boxed (stored in an object), that's expensive and defeats the point of using a value type in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

The main difference between ref and value types is that ref types contain pointers to their data, while value types contain the actual data. For most uses, that is worker classes, GUI classes, utility classes, you'll want to use the ref types. If, on the other hand, you're writing a simple class or structure which wraps e.g. a double you can use the value type.

ref class or struct will create reference types. They are created on the managed heap and only references (like pointers when you think of it natively) to those objects are stored and passed.

value class or struct are value types. When you pass them around as parameters or as members the whole memory block will be transferred. So you should use value types only for small data types.